# Why window.open do not opens a link which is given as var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a link which is in a div called hemsida.

```
 $('#hemsida').unbind('click');
 $('#hemsida').bind('click', function(){
    console.log('text: '+$(this).html());
    window.open($(this).html());
});
```

But new window opens a wrong link. For example if text in div hemsida is hotmail.com, then link for new opening window is http://localhost.com/hotmail.com. console.log is giving right string. Any idea why? and do i have to change my div hemsida to a href to make it work or can i open a link by getting text from it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: read the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide a protocol in your URL, the browser assumes you're providing a relative path for the current domain. You need to provide "`http://hotmail.com`".

Answer (score 3):

`hotmail.com` is a [**Relative URL**](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html).

Change this to `http://hotmail.com` for an **Absolute URL**, and this should fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't pass `http://` to a link, the browser assumes that it is local relative link, therefore tries to open it like http://localhost.com/hotmail.com.

Make sure your links start with http://

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert your link with before:

> http://

You needo to link

> "http://hotmail.com".

Because you need to use an absolute link not a relative link